# Product List Views not populating in Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have set up Enhanced Ecommerce using Google Tag Manager and dataLayer. Everything works well except impressions

[image]

View for list 4,5,6,7 is zero whilst they have been clicked many times. I have debugged data layer and it's sending impressions correctly.

[image]

Comment: Can you please show the complete code you are using to push the EE impression to the dataLayer?

Comment: Add an 'event':productImpression and a Tag with a trigger for that event and it should work just fine.